# applicationContext.xml file not being read in by Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I've been reading a ton of examples in StackOverflow on the subject of ApplicationContextProvider, but I can't find a single one that addresses my problem.  I have an xml file that I don't believe is being read in and initializing the beans that I note in it.  I have the following class:

```
package com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    @Autowired
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("ApplicationContext Initialized");
        context = ac;
    }       
}
```

My applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tacticalenterprisesltd" />
    <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.ApplicationContextProvider" />
    <bean id="springDatabase" class="com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.SpringDatabase" />

</beans>
```

JedSpringTestApplication:

```
package com.tacticalenterprisesltd.jedspringtest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tacticalenterprisesltd"})
public class JedSpringTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JedSpringTestApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

and finally, PersonelSearch class:

```
package com.tacticalenterprisesltd.jedspringtest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.tacticalenterprisesltd.Field;
import com.tacticalenterprisesltd.Query;
import com.tacticalenterprisesltd.WhereCondition;
import com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.ApplicationContextProvider;
import com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.SpringDatabase;

@Controller
public class PersonnelSearch 
{
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider ;

    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public String search(@RequestParam(value="lastname", required=true) String lastname, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("lastname", lastname);
        SpringDatabase sd = (SpringDatabase)applicationContextProvider .getApplicationContext().getBean("springDatabase", com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.SpringDatabase.class);
        Query query = new Query(Query.Type.SELECT, "employees");
        Field field1 = new Field("employees", "id", Field.Type.INT);
        Field field2 = new Field("employees", "first_name", Field.Type.STRING);
        Field field3 = new Field("employees", "last_name", Field.Type.INT);
        Field field4 = new Field("employees", "email", Field.Type.INT);
        Field[] fields = new Field[4];
        fields[0] = field1;
        fields[1] = field2;
        fields[2] = field3;
        fields[3] = field4;
        query.setFields(fields);
        WhereCondition where = new WhereCondition(field3, lastname, "=");
        WhereCondition[] conditions = new WhereCondition[1];
        conditions[0] = where;
        query.setWhereConditions(conditions);
        sd.setQuery(query);
        String[][] strData = sd.executeSelect();
        String out = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < strData.length; i++)
        {
            out += " | ";
            for(int j = 0; j < strData[0].length; j++)
            {
                out += strData[i][j] + " | ";
            }
            out += "\n";
        }
        System.out.println("Table Results:\n" + out);
        return out;
    }
}
```

When I run this as a Spring Boot application I get:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personnelSearch': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationContextProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.ApplicationContextProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

    Description:

Field applicationContextProvider in com.tacticalenterprisesltd.jedspringtest.PersonnelSearch required a bean of type 'com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.ApplicationContextProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.ApplicationContextProvider' in your configuration.
```

I'm thinking that the applicationContext.xml file is not being read in, otherwise the beans that are noted inside it would be available when the application loads.  Please advise.

Comment: Remove the equality to null, like this: ApplicationContextProvider acp;

Comment: I changed the line ApplicationContextProvider acp = null; to just ApplicationContextProvider acp;  Then I ran the application again.  Same result.

Comment: AFAIK, if you mark a class with `@Component` annotation, spring instantiates and injects the bean for you. You are again telling spring to create the same bean in applicationContext.xml using `<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.tacticalenterprisesltd.spring.ApplicationContextProvider" />`. Either one is suffice, can you remove the above xml node and retry?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot and as such your XML file isn't read unless you explicitly import it with `@ImportResource` on your spring application. However what you are doing is basically a code smell/bad habit. You shouldn't use the context to lookup beans you should use dependency injection instead. (Generally when you resort to these kind of solution you want to step away from the keyboard and take a good look at your solution again, as you are generally doing it wrong then).

Comment: you have declared the context as `static`. Try to remove `static`.

Comment: In response to M. Deinum, so if I am to understand you correctly, I really don't need the applicationContext.xml file at all if I am declaring my ApplicationContextProvider as @Component, yes?  That being said, I removed the xml file from the project and ran it again.  Same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't `@Autowired` your Application context.

You need to do it like this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext()
    {
        return context;
    }
```

}

Comment: I added the annotation as you suggested and ran the application again.  It didn't make any difference.  I got the same result.

Comment: Your class ApplicationContextProvider isn't implementing  ApplicationContextAware.

Comment: You do not have to, you can just auto wire it.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the name of the variable from `acp` to `applicationContextProvider` in the `PersonnelSearch` class OR add `@Qualifier("applicationContextProvider")` after `@Autowired` in `PersonnelSearch` for `acp` variable.

e.g.

```
@Controller
public class PersonnelSearch 
{
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider;
```

**OR**

```
@Controller
public class PersonnelSearch 
    {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("applicationContextProvider")
        ApplicationContextProvider acp;
```

Also, add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tacticalenterprisesltd"})` on `JedSpringTestApplication` as:

```
package com.tacticalenterprisesltd.jedspringtest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tacticalenterprisesltd"})
public class JedSpringTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JedSpringTestApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Comment: I added the annotation Qualifier as suggested and ran the app again.  Same result.

Comment: Based on the comments so far, I've updated my code as seen above.  However, I'm no further ahead.